# How to pass a struct as a pointer? [C++]

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers

I have a struct that I'm passing through CreateThread

```
packetargs *args;
args->s=s;
args->buf=buf;
args->len=len;
args->flags=flags;
args->to=to;
args->tolen=tolen;
CreateThread(NULL,0,mThread,args,0,NULL);
```

But when I receive it in my Thread function, it crashes the application(Because the information is wrong):

```
DWORD WINAPI mThread(LPVOID args)
{
    packetargs *pargs = (packetargs *)args;
```

How am I supposed to pass the struct as a pointer and then create it again in the thread function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to allocate any memory for your struct:

```
packetargs *args = new packetargs;
```

(Of course, you'll need to `delete` it at some point.)

Comment: The structs still seem to contain different information after it's passed. I have no idea why

Comment: It might also be possible just to create the args struct as an automatic variable. Obviously make sure it lives long enough for the new thread to use it, safest is to ensure it lives until after you join that thread.

Comment: Something is going wrong on this line  packetargs *pargs = (packetargs *)args;

Comment: @Nowayz: You'll need to edit your question to include your *actual* code (cut down to the minimum possible).